# (TypeScript) Type Alias / Interface defined by object literal

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am making some schema of JSON message to transfer between server & client, for serialization I created an object literal as a template such as below

```
type uint8 = number;

const schema1 = {
    type: 'object',
    fields: {
        type: { type: 'uint8' },
        title: { type: 'string', optional: true }
    }
};

// can below automatically defined by schema1?
type schema1Type = {
    type: number,
    title?: string
};

const data1: schema1Type = {
    type: 1,
    title: 'Hello World'
};
```

It is alright to validate the message format by object literal schema (type alias seems cannot do this job in runtime), but for more comprehensive usage, I wish to define a type alias according to the object literal template, to guard message format in compile time, is it possible to do so? please sharing some hints for me, thank you.

Comment: Is that a JSON schema?

Comment: You are asking schema1? it is a self-made schema for my project which I compose a Class can using the schema to validate, serialize & deserialize a data object (eg. data1 in my example)

Comment: What a fun question. Thank you.

Comment: @DevHang If it was a [json schema](https://json-schema.org), there are tools to generate TS type definitions from the schema file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're going to need to the type for your schema definitions. I'm thinking something like this:

```
interface SchemaOptional { optional?: boolean }

interface SchemaNumber extends SchemaOptional { type: 'uint8' | 'int8' | 'float' }
interface SchemaString extends SchemaOptional { type: 'string' }
interface SchemaObject extends SchemaOptional {
    type: 'object',
    fields: Record<string, SchemaEntry>
}

type SchemaEntry = SchemaObject | SchemaNumber | SchemaString
```

Here we have a type for each type that each entry can be. And that `SchemaEntry` is a union of all possible types.

Note that `SchemaObject` here has `fields` that are a dictionary of keys and other schema entries. This should allow for recursive nesting.

---

Next up we need a type that will transform each entry to its proper type.

```
type SchemaToType<T extends SchemaEntry> =
    // Does this entry extend the number schema type? Then return number
    T extends SchemaNumber ? number :

    // Does this entry extend the string schema type? Then return string
    T extends SchemaString ? string :

    // Does this entry extend the object schema type? Then return an object
    T extends SchemaObject ? SchemaObjectToType<T> :

    // No match, return never
    never
```

This conditional type checks to see if `T` is a specific kind of entry, and then returns a type for that kind of entry. If the entry is a `string` or `number`, then those types are returned. But if it's an `object`, we have more work to do, so we invoke the `SchemaObjectToType` type which looks like this:

```
type SchemaObjectToType<T extends SchemaObject> = {
    // For each key in the `fields` object
    [K in keyof T['fields']]:

        // return a union of the type for that entry and...
        | SchemaToType<T['fields'][K]>

        // ...and undefined if the property is optional or never if it's required
        | SchemaEntryIsOptional<T['fields'][K]>
}
```

This mapped type maps over all properties in the `fields` object, and invokes `SchemaToType` on that field to get its real type. This allows the type to be recursive, since `SchemaToType` can call `SchemaObjectToType`, and `SchemaObjectToType` can call `SchemaToType`.

The last line will check if the entry is optional. Let's look at that type:

```
type SchemaEntryIsOptional<T extends SchemaEntry> =
    T['optional'] extends true ? undefined : never
```

This type will return `undefined` if it's optional, or `never` if it's required. A union with `undefined` is *more or less* the same thing as optional, so that should work fine.

---

Let's give that some simple tests:

```
type TestA = SchemaToType<{ type: 'string' }>
// string

type TestB = SchemaToType<{ type: 'uint8' }>
// number

type TestC = SchemaToType<{ type: 'object', fields: { a: { type: 'string' }}}>
// { a: string }

type TestD = SchemaToType<{ type: 'object', fields: { a: { type: 'string', optional: true }}}>
// { a: string | undefined }
```

So far so good. How about your `schema1` object?

```
const schema1 = {
    type: 'object',
    fields: {
        type: { type: 'uint8' },
        title: { type: 'string', optional: true }
    }
} as const; // the `as const` here is important

type Schema1Type = SchemaToType<typeof schema1>
/*
type Schema1Type = {
    readonly type: number;
    readonly title: string | undefined;
}
*/
```

Looks like it works!

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoIBYQLZwPIAOYwA9iHADbIDeyJRp5FA-AFzIBGJJFEcIyAL4AoYaEixEKdFlwA5AK7YO0ZBAAekEABMAzmkw58DMpRrIwATwIR2AcgXiAHHeQAfZHeeuPdmBRI4MFcRcWh4JANZOFQwKFAAczVNCB19GSNCYlMqWisbe104xJCxcHCpKMyOACsIBDBkrT0q3CzGM2phZB6La1tPElr64IAabt6YYAgKPXYAJXqSKG0AHiL4kATR1rgAUXAoSwA+YRFhfOlDXAO4y2QAXl28YYb3XcVlVQ8M3FjNhKiS7PV5gAAqJDB-VWYKaqRav3woOOjxoEx6AG0ANLIUDIADWEEsJBgyDBGL801mujsAF1aax0b0ej9rnAIVCbDCKVMZno6djaadmczWdFbkcAJK6do5bmUvk02mC07nYGIiWWaWypgwuFpXaalEPJnkuz0bJMOn6lpxBQoZjIBQ6CBTEAQbTIdjugBu0CB-V2HOhsI0zXSbKNj1NNoj0U+KigyEdICUia9MbD8LjRn+iWTyA2+cZzNDKQNiJedTejsroODXLBKJLvV9-ougbBECKAEFUYiGxBVnl+oVilsQqcAPRTwvjwEdmxk7tgABC-bZg+HfQKnkc4BcQmns9TXygAaXXaKAGEN9EtyPd+bQXYdrzqexaHBPzuBnYixOQiCIIx7mN+c4AkIF4oFeYAACJ3kYD6-vYQzVmMyDvnMYE-pcY4Aq+dAmEw7B2igwEgcIM44RB+YeM62iuqAHpQcICBkEUhZsgAjKiXTMnhgwvuMzJYbon5MgJo7mIJDjeEIIkij0xBgLwuHSf+86ERaHQUKRUD2lBzIiIIyBwPo7EgEUADc0G7NxnIoE8A6QtClwklx0TcdOABUi5XF5jl8UyUB8NoZAUPcgmnomtnMqFcDhSAkUWMAqkDABST0S6boerZIg+VOwhAA)

Comment: WOW, Thank your quick detail solution, I think I need sometime to digest :)

Comment: Your solution is wonderful, especially "as const", although I not really understand how the trick work. Thank you very much